# JTable Вывод заголовков таблицы

Tags: java, jtable

Как можно вывести на консоль заголовки таблицы, используя объект таблицы/модели?

`final JTable table = new JTable(data,colNames);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код

```
    Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while ( columns.hasMoreElements() ) {
        TableColumn column = columns.nextElement();
        System.out.println( column.getHeaderValue() );
    }
```

или

```
    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    for ( int index = 0; index < columnModel.getColumnCount(); index += 1 ) {
        TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn( index );
        System.out.println( column.getHeaderValue() );
    }
```

выведет заголовки (текст над колонками) видимых колонок в порядке отображения в таблице.

```
    for ( int index = 0; index < table.getColumnCount(); index += 1 ) {
        System.out.println( table.getColumnName( index ) );
    }
```

выведет имена (то, что возвращает `TableModel.getColumnName( int index )` колонок в порядке отображения.